# Given constraints on norm of a Matrix, what conclusions can we draw on an infinite matrix series

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Say we have some matrix $M$ which is $n × n$. if we know, for instance, that $||M|| <= \frac{1}{2}$, then what can we say about the infinite series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty M^{i-1}\vec{\alpha}$, where $\vec{\alpha}$ is an arbitrary vector $\in R^n$. I suspect that this is sufficient information to prove that such a series converges, but I am unsure of exactly how to do so. I know such a question can probably be answered through looking at the spectral radius of the Matrix, but is there a more simple way? Would someone mind helping me out? Moreover, is it possible to determine what this series converges to?

Comment: $M$ is also real right?

Comment: Yes, $M$ is real

Comment: You may check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm having a tough time seeing how that is directly applicable to the convergence of this series. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} M^{i-1} \vec{\alpha} = (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} M^{i-1}) \vec{\alpha}$. And we know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} M^{i-1}$ converges (to $(I - M)^{-1}$) if $||M|| < 1$

Comment: I see, is the general argument that if $||M|| < 1$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n M^{i-1}$ simply functions as a power series $\sum_{i=1}^n p^k$ which is obviously convergent when $p < 1$? Is that a sound way to understand this?

Comment: yes you can understand this as a generalization of the power series

Comment: Just curious, but how might we do this using cauchy convergence to prove it?